# Line spacing not working in title created using a parbox

Tags: titles, line-spacing, parbox

I am having some problems with the line spacing on my title page. My title is placed in a parbox and it was all fine until the title went more than 3 lines and then it became all squished up. Code and picture of PDF below.

I have tried using line spacing within the parbox and this makes no difference. I don't know if there is a way to make the parbox vertically bigger as I have plenty of space on the page and my gut feeling is that this is the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\begin{document}    
\begin{titlepage}

        \raggedleft 

        \rule{1pt}{\textheight} 
        \hspace{0.05\textwidth} 
        \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{

            \begin{flushleft}
            \nohyphens{{\Huge Title: This is the title of the report and it is quite a long title so goes over several lines and then becomes all squished up}}\\[2\baselineskip] 
            {\large\textit{Report has a date etc}}\\[4\baselineskip] 

            \end{flushleft}
            \vspace{0.25\textheight} 

            {\noindent Version 0.1}\\[\baselineskip] 
        }
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to complete small document which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Edited. Should work on it's own now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if the following MWE will give what you after:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \raggedleft
    \rule{1pt}{\textheight}
    \hspace{0.05\textwidth}
    \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{
        \raggedright
        \Huge Title: This is the title of the report and it is quite a long title so goes over several lines and then becomes all squished up

        \vspace{2\baselineskip}
        \large\textit{Report has a date \today}

        \vspace{0.25\textheight}
        \noindent Version 0.1
    }
\end{titlepage}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Now code fragment is completed to MWE.

*Note:*

- Use of \ [4\baselineskip] in your case is wrong. You need first terminate paragraph (in my MWE is done by empty line) and then add desired vertical space, for example with `\vspace{2\baselineskip}`.
- Use of `\raggedright` prohibit hyphenation, so `\nohyphens` command is superfluous.

Comment: Yes thanks. The original code was copied from a template and I think it just ended up with too many curly brackets and it didn't like the \\[4\baselineskip]. I started again based on your code above and it has worked great.

Comment: @Charlie, your conclusion is correct.  Use of `\ \[4\baselineskip]` in your case is wrong. You need first terminate paragraph (in my code fragment is done by empty line) and then ad desired vertical space. use of `\raggedright` doesn't allows hyphenation, so `\nohyphens` is superfluous.

Comment: Yeah it was justified originally hence the use of \nohyphens was left in. Thanks for your help.